# SQL Server varbinary(max) to Image data type

Tags: sql-server, image

I've got a database table that stores images as varbinary(max). This works great for me. However, I have to now send this data to a MS Dynamics database that will have to use the Image data type.

Is there anything I need to be aware of when saving varbinary(max) to image?  Can my data become corrupted, or are they generally the same datatype for all intents and purposes?

Thanks

Comment: Given that the `image` type [becomes deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) in SQL Server and Microsoft recommends replacing it with `varbinary(max)`, I would assume that the two are indeed equivalent. However I've never tried to convert `varbinary` to `image`, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to get rid of the Image datatype used in the 2nd database, but I'm kept from doing so as Microsoft Dynamics won't support the varbinary(max) even if the database it's using does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same thing and handled the same internaly.  They droped the image name because it dosn't really make sense.  Its not like sqlserver can do image operations in tsql

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much determined the same thing by creating a table with both field types and swapping the data contained in each. I could find no discrepancies in my data after the swaps.